# How to remove non-letters from a string in script?

Tags: string, bash, shell

I have:

```
something='sl89wS Gjf-_32b'
```

I want to return:

```
slwsgjfb
```

How can I make it return only letters and then make everything lowercase?

Comment: You forgot to post your code. StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Parameter Expansion:

```
${something//[^[:alpha:]]/}
```

here all non-alphabetic characters (`[^[:alpha:]]`) of variable `something`  will be replaced by none i.e. will be omitted.

**Example:**

```
$ str='sl89wS Gjf-_32b'
$ echo "${str//[^[:alpha:]]/}"
slwSGjfb
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea would be to replace everything that is not a letter:

```
[^a-Z]
```

by nothing:

```
$ s='sl8zZ9wS Gjf-_32b'
$ echo "${s//[^a-Z]}"
slzZwSGjfb
```

That works for a `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`. However, that idea fails if the characters used include accented glyphs (assuming accented glyphs are not desired):

```
$ s='sl8zZ9wS Gjf-_3éëì2b'
$ echo "${s//[^a-Z]}"
slzZwSGjféëìb
```

or the collate order change:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=C
$ echo "${s//[^a-z]}"
slzwjfb                       ### Missing upper chars.
```

In those cases, a more reliable list of characters is needed:

```
$ s='sl8zZ9wS Gjf-_3éëì2b'
$ echo "${s//[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]}"
slzZwSGjfb
```

The final reliable command line should be:

```
$ s="$( LC_ALL=C eval printf '%s' "${s//[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]}" )"
```

Or shorter (if the collating order is ASCII byte value):

```
$ s="$( LC_ALL=C eval printf '%s' "${s//[^a-zA-Z]}" )"
```

And adding the conversion to upper characters:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${s^^}"
SLZZWSGJFB
```

All under bash, of course.

Comment: or, `[^a-zA-Z]` to avoid removing caps. (or use your `${s^^}` prior to character removal -- but that defeats preserving case if that is needed)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `[^a-zA_Z]` will only work correctly if the collating order is `ASCII byte value`, not in general. Assuming you meant that: answer edited.